# Phalcon find with columns parameter returns rows instead models

Tags: php, models, phalcon

When I use `Model::find()` response is Resultset of Models, but when I add `columns` parameter to restrict returned columns the response is Resultset of Rows.

Example:

```
// Resultset of Models
$users = \Models\Users\Users::find();

// Resultset of Rows
$users = \Models\Users\Users::find([
        'columns' => 'id, email'
]);
```

That makes me unable to call model methods. Is there a way to have Resultset of Models with columns restriction in ::find() method? I'm not sure, but this seems like bug, since Phalcon docs says:

> While findFirst() returns directly an instance of the called class (when there is data to be returned), the find() method returns a Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple.

And there is nothing about the exception of this rule when using `columns` parameter.

I would also note that other parameters of ::find() like `condition`, `order`, `bind` etc. works fine (Models returned).

Phalcon 1.3.4

Comment: When selecting specific columns, you will always get a `Resultset of Rows` because Phalcon is unable to return your complete `Users` Model structure, therefor it wont be "recognized" as a `Users` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug, it is the expected behaviour. 
Info in [the docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#finding-records) scroll a bit down to the Parameters table and read description of **columns**.

If you need to use model methods or relations you should not specify columns. But if you are after better performance and do not need model relations you should use the [Query Builder](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Query_Builder.html).

Rest of the find() parameters like condition, order e.t.c. will, not affect your ability to use model methods.

The findFirst() method is also working like the find() method. Example here:

**No columns specified:**

```
News::findFirst(3);

// Output
Models\News Object
(
...
```

**When specifying columns**

```
News::findFirst([
    'columns' => 'id, created_at'
]);

// Output
Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Row Object
(
    [id] => 1
    [created_at] => 2016-02-02
)
```

Comment: `findFirst()` basically _comes down to_ calling `getFirst()` on your `find()` object. `find()->getFirst()`

Comment: Exactly and it's eye candy, also you can use the magic methods like `findFirstByName('Timothy');` :)

Comment: As wrote above this is expected behaviour and won't ever be changed. You can still access properties beacause this is an object.

Though we could perhaps add some magic getter/setter.

Comment: When it comes to `find()` and `findFirst()` I know that behaviour is the same. Now I understand why with `columns` I can't get Model. This seems obvious, but I didn't think that having just few columns make it unable to create properly working Model. Thanks for explanation :)